# Reading select columns with missing data

Tags: r, fread, read.table

Imagine I have the following text file named d.txt

```
   PLANT       Jan-15   Feb-15   Mar-15   Apr-15   May-15   Jun-15       Jul-15    Aug-15   Sep-15     Oct-15  Nov-15  Dec-15  TOTAL
FirmA               23,893   18,593   19,182   22,798   10,294   22,017       22,251    20,352                                      159,380
B          11,957   25,752   34,608   30,960   29,662   30,979       32,311    35,918                                      232,147
PlantC         42,446   36,670   42,324   41,958   32,441   37,264       38,661    38,721                                      310,485
D   172,698  153,871  176,128  161,132  160,413  146,511      172,363   182,238                                     1,325,355
```

I want to read the first nine columns (i.e. Plant and Jan-15 until Aug-15), but I've been unsuccessful.

#### Failed attempts

1. I tried `read.table(paste0(path.txt, "\\d.txt"), colClasses = c(rep(NA, 9), rep(NULL, 5)), header = TRUE)`, however, this did not work. The call to `read.table` correctly assigns 14 columns to the `data.frame`, however, the missing variable imply that each column does not have 14 elements.
2. I tried a `fread` approach as it has the `select` and `drop` options.  However, loading data whose delimiter is multiple white spaces not feasible in `fread` to my knowledge.
3. For a second I thought `read.fwf`, however, the staggered nature of the data makes this unfeasible.

## Desired Output:

```
    Plant  Jan-15  Feb-15  Mar-15  Apr-15  May-15  Jun-15  Jul-15  Aug-15
1:  FirmA  23,893  18,593  19,182  22,798  10,294  22,017  22,251  20,352
2:      B  11,957  25,752  34,608  30,960  29,662  30,979  32,311  35,918
3: PlantC  42,446  36,670  42,324  41,958  32,441  37,264  38,661  38,721
4:      D 172,698 153,871 176,128 161,132 160,413 146,511 172,363 182,238
```

Comment: You might have to hack something together with `strsplit` - `sapply(lapply(strsplit(trimws(txt,"left"),"\n"), strsplit, split="\\s+")[[1]], \`[\`, 1:9)` seems to work.

Comment: @thelatemail I think that will destroy data, unless I'm mistaken.. the problem is some of the white space is meaningful (it seems). JacobH some desired output would be nice.

Comment: @thelatemail `do.call("rbind", lapply(...))` instead of `sapply(...)` is probably more accurate, though it's a lot tougher if there are any rows missing data before column 9

Comment: @MichaelChirico - my code gives me the expected output (transposed, but whatever) - the problems only hit after `Aug-15` when there are blanks for data.

Comment: @MichaelChirico thank you for including the desired output.  It is exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: @thelatemail and MichaelChirico, thanks for the solutions.  To load the data I needed to run `data <- paste(readLines(path\to\data), collapse = "\n")`.

Comment: BTW @thelatemail I'd gladly give you a +1 if you post an answer.  IMO the question and answer is substantial enough.